# Stopping Statement Execution Until true

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I am trying to handle user input using `pysimplegui`.

If the user enters any value in the input box I need to make sure it's an integer type.

If successful, I need to replace user input value with default value for it.

I tried to use `try` `except` within a `while` loop. My concern here is if the user enters a string value I need to give a retry option.

However, the `if` `else` block below the `try` block is getting executed.
How can I make sure to give the option for the user to retry entering a value?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('SandyBeach')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please enter your Phone')],
    [sg.Text('Phone', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(key="lp1", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Button("e"), sg.Quit()]
]
window = sg.Window('Simple data entry window', layout)
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Quit"):
        break
    elif event == "e":

        text = values['lp1']
        log_timer = 1200
        user_input = None

        if text == '':
            log_timer = 1200
        else:
            while True:
                try:
                    user_input = int(text)
                    break

                except ValueError:
                    sg.popup_error("Only Integer Allowed")
                    break
```

I need to stop the below block if a string value is entered.

```
        if type(user_input) == int:

            log_timer = user_input
            print(log_timer)

        elif log_timer == 1200:
            print("no cha")

window.close()
```

Comment: Your second `while True:` is useless. You `break` out of it in both cases.

Comment: for checking i had added  coz if i  remove the break on try & keep on except ui gets stuck on loop can u kindly suggest to fix it

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of noise in your code.
When you reduce it to only what you need it becomes a lot clearer.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('SandyBeach')

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please enter your Phone')],
    [sg.Text('Phone', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(key="lp1", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Button("e"), sg.Quit()]
]
window = sg.Window('Simple data entry window', layout)
# Add some defaults for user_input and log_timer
user_input = None
log_timer = 1200
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    text = values['lp1']
    # break on Quit
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Quit"):
        break
    elif event == "e" and text != '':
        # Attempt to convert to int
        try:
            user_input = int(text)
        except ValueError:
            sg.popup_error("Only Integers Allowed")
        # If the attempt was unsuccessful user_input will remain None
        if user_input is not None:
            # the only place log_timer is changed from the default
            log_timer = user_input
            break
print(log_timer)
window.close()
```

The two `break`s in your code mean it will only stop running on 2 conditions.
A valid number is entered. Or the quit button was pressed.

Having one place that `log_timer` is reassigned means the only way it can change from the default is if a valid number is entered.

There are obviously improvements to be made once you learn functions and so on. But this is a good starting point.

Comment: thnks this is wht i was looking for